# Get string value from AngularJS directive tag: my-first-directive="I want this"

Tags: angularjs

I am wanting to pass a string value to my AngularJS directive without using a separate attribute, something like this...

In my HTML

```
<div my-first-directive="number 1"></div>
<div my-first-directive="number 2"></div>
<div my-first-directive="number 3"></div>
```

and in my JavaScript

```
.directive('myFirstDirective', function () {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element) {
            // now I want the string that follows the directive
            console.log(element[0].attributes[0].nodeValue);
            console.log(element[0].attributes[0].textContent);
            console.log(element[0].attributes[0].value);
            }
        };
    });
```

Now all the three `console.log` methods output the string I require... however I am unsure this isn't the best way to obtain such a value, don't I need to think about isolate scope and the like? I don't require "2 way binding" or anything. Is there a better or AngularJS way of obtaining the string?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`link()` takes an `attrs` argument, you will find what you want there:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    // what you want is:
    console.log(attrs.myFirstDirective);
}
```

The attribute names are normalized.